# VS Code Vim: How do you highlight current line?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

How do you highlight the current line using Vim VS Code?

This functionality would be awesome. Anyone know if this configuration is possible in Vim VS Code? http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_current_line

Especially Highlighting that stays after cursor moves:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <Leader>l ml:execute 'match Search /\%'.line('.').'l/'<CR>
```

Answer (score 38):

Try this in your settings.json:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#ff0000"
}
```

This assumes that you have

```
  "editor.renderLineHighlight": "line",
```

(that is the default) set to "line" or ""all".

[EDIT after your comment about selecting]

I am not exactly sure what you are looking to do but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>  selects the current line and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> highlights the entire line but doesn't select it.  In neither case does the highlighting stay on a previous line after you move the cursor.

Comment: Mark thanks for your help! I'm looking to hilight/select the current line so that I can manipulate it. Currently in Vim normal mode I move the curser to the start of the line and then toggle visual mode and jump to the end of the line, but I'm sure there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: `"editor.renderLineHighlight": "all"` is nice too, bigger focus than `line` only (includes line numbers plus gutter then)

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> toggles visual line, not sure if you've discovered that yet or not.

It's worth pointing out that in Vim, you don't need to highlight to act on or manipulate the current line (as I see you're trying to do in your comment to another answer). In fact, it's often better/faster not to. For example:

- <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>: delete linewise
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>: delete from cursor to end of line
- <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>: yank linewise
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>: yank from cursor to end of line
- <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>: change linewise
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>: change from cursor to end of line
- <kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd>: indent line
- <kbd><</kbd><kbd><</kbd>: unindent line

If you find yourself in visual mode a lot, that can be a sign that you haven't yet become comfortable with [text object motions](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#object-motions) and [text object selection](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#object-select).

Comment: Shift+v to highlight, and again to undo, exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can use `shift`+`alt`+`RightArrow` to select parts within current line.

Hope this helps