# How to change styling of currently selected line in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I updated Visual Studio Code and the appearance of the currently selected line of code in the editor window has changed and now looks like this:

[image: example]

I tried searching online and reading their documentation, but it is not clear how to change the appearance of the highlighted line. I would like it to be one consistent color, it currently looks like a 1.5px outline. Does anyone know how to change this in the user settings file?

Comment: See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938552/vs-code-vim-how-do-you-highlight-current-line/47945273#47945273 "editor.lineHighlightBackground" is what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outline is coming from the `editor.lineHighlightBorder` setting. In your [user or workspace settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings), add the following properties and then experiment with the colors until they match your preferences.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editor.lineHighlightBorder": "#222",
  "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#222",
}
```

If you prefer, you can ensure the settings only apply to a specific theme:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "[Material Theme High Contrast]": {
    "editor.lineHighlightBorder": "#222",
    "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#222",
  }
}
```